# Is there anything like jquery for WPF/XAML?

Tags: jquery, wpf, xaml

As the title says: Is there anything that is for XAML what jquery is for HTML?

If not, would it be possible to create such a framework?

Comment: Can you clarify what you think jQuery is to HTML?

Comment: It would be cool to have css selectors for XAML, or use Xpath

Comment: I, too, am searching for an equivalent but have, unfortunately, found nothing.

Comment: What about C#? Sorry, not sure what you think jQuery is to HTML. Perhaps you can elaborate.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://xamlquery.codeplex.com/

> [...] In short, what XamlQuery aims to do to Silverlight is similar to what jQuery does to JavaScript.

Comment: CodePlex link doesn't work anymore. Please use this link: https://github.com/cincoutprabu/xamlquery